# Copying data of one array with transformation into another array in javascript/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

My API is returning below output.

```
[
    "ANT",
    "ARG",
    "ARM",
    "BUR",
    "UAE"
]
```

in my array I need to store `countryname` corresponding to these `countrycode`.
so for that I have used `country-data` library in `react`.
so I can get output like `console.log(countries["UAE"].name);`
I need to store country name in my `countryData` array which is declared below.

my react code is.

```
 this.state = {
      countryData: [],
    };
```

I am using arraycode like below.

```
updateDropdownData() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/country_code`).then((res) => {        
      res.data.map((code) => {
        alert(countries[code].name);
        countryData.push.apply(countryData, countries[code].name);
      });
      this.setState({ countryData });
    });
  }
```

but I am getting error

```
index.bundle.js:122 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: countryData is not defined
    at index.bundle.js:122:217123
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

what mistake I am doing. I am quite new in `javascript` and `react`.

Edit1:-
`alert(countries[res.data[0]].name);` //this line is working.

but `const _countryData = res.data.map((code) => countries[code].name);`  giving error.
[image]

Comment: How about declaring it then before the mapping task starts?

Comment: And did the OP ever asks him/herself what `countryData.push.apply(countryData, countries[code].name);` is good for? Doesn't the OP not just want to directly [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) `countries[code].name` into the (before declared) `countryData` array?

Comment: Thank you Peter. Now I am getting one weird error. I have edited the question and put in the end. Could you please check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the state value directly does not fit React's method.

```js
updateDropdownData() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/country_code`).then((res) => {
      const _countryData = res.data.map((code) => countries[code].name )        
      this.setState({ countryData: _countryData });
    });
  }
```

### EDIT

> The `countries` variable must be where you run it. And the shape of
> the variable should be as follows.

```
const countries = {
    "ANT" : { name : "ant_name"  },
    "ARG" : { name : "arg_name"  },
    ...
}
```

Comment: ofcourse...Hong. actually this is giving one minor error. could you please check. I have edited the question.

Comment: @Oze I added an answer.

Comment: Thanks hong. what i need to change in my main code?  I imported library like import { countries } from 'country-data';